# 32 bit Windows on 64 bit hardware for 32 bit apps

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework

There is a 32-bits App and 64-bits PC (Hardware). The Hardware vendor says : for running a 32-bit app on 64-bit PC, Win7 32-bits is enough to get maximum performance for the app.

I disagree, because if Windows 64 then it supposed to be optimal for working under 64 bits hardware, even if the App is 32.

We've argued..

So my question is: what configuration will result in highest performance for 32-bit App - "Win32 on 64 PC" or "Win64 on 64 PC"?

Comment: The reason for developing a 64 bit OS wasn't performance. It was primarily to provide a much larger virtual address space for native 64 bit applications, and a smaller address space increase for those 32 bit applications that can handle it. When a 64 bit application is faster it is just a bonus.

Comment: More so for the memory issue, because a 32-bit app on 32-bit OS will have maximum 2GB allocation, on a 64-bit OS it can use 4GB. ( - overhead)

Comment: Thank you.. what I've understood for sure is if the app process huge data from disk (MS SQL) then 64 bits OS + 64 MS SQL should be considered first of all, and then 32 bit app..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What will result in highest performance for 32-bit App - "Win32 on 64 PC" or "Win64 on 64 PC"?

The answer is - it depends. The only way to find out is to perform benchmarks.

> Sometimes 32-bit applications run faster, sometimes they run slower.
>   There are a lot of competing factors affecting the performance.
>   Generally the difference in either direction isn't very large.
>
> I don't see how you can legitimately exclude any factor from
>   performance considerations, because performance always happens in the
>   real world where all factors are in play. Speed is not theoretical and
>   cannot be treated in isolation.
>
> Here is an article where the author did some benchmarking:
>
> http://www.osnews.com/story/5768
>
> He found that the 32-bit binaries were faster in his tests. That was
>   on SPARC in early 2004.
>
> Here is a 2010 article from Intel about moving to 64-bit applications:
>
> http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/moving-from-32-bit-applications-to-64-bit-applications-en/
>
> According to this article, 64-bit binaries can giver you faster math,
>   so math-heavy code should be faster if correctly optimized. Otherwise,
>   your 64-bit code may well be slower, particular since it takes more
>   memory and this may result in more time spent accessing RAM (more
>   frequent cache misses).

Source [Do 32bit apps run faster or slower on a 64bit OS? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12224947/3536342), answer by [nate-c-k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219155/nate-c-k)

Comment: Correct.  When dealing with just "bitness" there isnt a real difference.  64 bit processors do allow for more memory allocation, which can increase performance, assuming the application *actually* needs more memory.  Generally speaking, unless the application was specifically designed to run with 64 architecture and optimizations, there is no benefit to 64 bitness.

Comment: Thank you.. what I've understood for sure is if the app process huge data from disk (MS SQL) then 64 bits OS + 64 MS SQL should be considered first of all, and then 32 bit app..